# I'm looking for user-interface or spring component for all the properties that are part of Spring cloud config?

Tags: user-interface, configuration-files, spring-cloud-config

As title suggests, I'm looking for a front end to view and change/edit property values that might be stored in GIT/file system. These property files might be in YML or properties file format. A one place to see all the relevant/applicable properties defined and option to edit on the fly.

I'm looking for pointers in this direction, on having an UI for all the configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any direct way where from UI you  access those. What I suggest is you can create an endpoint as your spring service.Pass the property which you want to read from frontend , and from backend you can send appropriate value reading it from git location. 
hope this helps

Comment: Ok, I think I need to re-frame my question. I wanted to have a placeholder where I can see all my properties related to one area/logical section and edit whichever I want. Not sure that sounds crazy requirement

Comment: I don't think there is something where you can list down all the properties. Regarding your question for modifying the property you can change it at GitHub only.

Comment: JFYI... with spring cloud config there is a facility where you can read the configuration from each branch and tag also. Also, keep in mind that once you update the GitHub config you need to call /refresh endpoint if your application is already running to load latest config

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of /refresh end point. Also I'm looking to way to trigger push notifications so that clients are aware of changes happened and take appropriate action on the event.